# Issues with absolute paths in Webpack/Vue/Vuetify/PWA Project

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I've created a new (WebPack, Vue, Vuetify, PWA) project in /var/www/html/testing:

```
vue init vuetifyjs/pwa myapp
cd myapp
yarn run dev
```

-> everything is fine in dev mode, page can be opened in http://localhost:8080

Production build:

```
yarn run build
```

-> ok, dist folder is created and populated:

```
/var/www/html/testing/myapp/dist
```

WebRoot of my ngninx server is /var/www/html, so I tried to open the prod version with this url:

```
http://localhost/testing/myapp/dist/
```

Problem: the App cannot be opened in the browser, since all paths are absolute, like in index.html:

```
<link rel=icon type=image/png sizes=32x32 href=/static/img/icons/favicon-32x32.png>
<link rel=manifest href=/static/manifest.json>
<link rel=preload href=/static/js/vendor.1c719443f0f3c271d7fd.js as=script>
```

and so on.

in manifest.json there is also an absolute path:

```
"start_url": "/index.html"
```

When changing my WebRoot to

```
/var/www/html/testing/myapp/dist
```

everything works as expected. But this is not an option. The target folder is not WebRoot, but some sub folder.

My guess: one or more changes in some config file should do the trick.

Q: how can I fix that?

- What file(s) is/are relevant,
- what setting(s) must be adjusted.

(yes, I've browsed thru some of the numerous config files in myapp, myapp/build, myapp/config, but I really don't see which file/setting has to be changed.)

BTW: there are 23478 files, but no 'webpack.config.js', I found these:

```
ls config/
dev.env.js  index.js  prod.env.js  test.env.js

ls build/
build.js           service-worker-dev.js   webpack.dev.conf.js
check-versions.js  service-worker-prod.js  webpack.prod.conf.js
dev-client.js      utils.js                webpack.test.conf.js
dev-server.js      vue-loader.conf.js
load-minified.js   webpack.base.conf.js
```

And one extra question: Why is an absolute path the default anyway? Relative paths should work fine. Very likely that there is a reason, but I can't see it.

Comment: relative paths don't work fine if you configure your webserver to serve separate subfolders to the main index, something that is needed in the default mode of vue router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: RTFM.

Then in:

```
config/index.js
```

change assetsPublicPath:

```
    ...
    // assetsPublicPath: '/',
    assetsPublicPath: './',
    ...
```

This assetsPublicPath is used in other config file to create the publicPath.

Be aware: there are warnings like the one from Ferrybig and others found here: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/200 :

If the publicPath is made relative then vue will have problems to deal with 'code splitting' (whatever this might be) and with 'split chunks' (whatever that might be)

However: No malicious side effects observed till now - fingers crossed.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case, if you're using **Vue CLI 3**, the solution is different, yet still pretty simple.

Edit your `vue.config.js` (if there is none, create it in project root directory) and add following lines:

```
module.exports = {
  baseUrl: "./"
};
```

Or whatever sub-directory you want.

You may also decide according to `NODE_ENV`. See the [docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#baseurl).

```
module.exports = {
  baseUrl: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/production-sub-path/'
    : '/'
}
```